# SpringBoot: How to send an Object via RestTemplate HttpMethod GET?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to SpringBoot and trying to figure out few things. I have a Request DTO and I want to send this as a part of the RestTemplate HttpMethod.GET call. How do we do that?

**DTO**

```
class User {

  String firstName;
  String lastName;

}
```

**MicroService 1**

```
User dto=new User("abc","xyz");

// Is this possible ?

HttpEntity<User> entity=new HttpEntity<>(dto);
restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Object.class);
```

If the above is possible, how to get the values of the User passed from the MicroService 1 in MicroService 2.

**MicroService 2**

```
// Is this possible ?

@GetMapping("/url")
Object getData(@RequestBody User user){

}
```

**If the above is not possible, then how to use HashMash to send data?**

**MicroService 1**

```
HashMap<String,String> map=new HashMap<>();
map.put("name", "abc");
HttpEntity<User> entity=new HttpEntity<>(map);

restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, Object.class);
```

Now how to get the values of the HashMap passed from the MicroService 1.

**MicroService 2**

```
// Is this possible ?

@GetMapping("/url")
Object getData(@RequestParam HashMap<String,String> user){

   sysout(user) // Null

}
```

Comment: scenario 1 with user dto should be working fine, did you get any error? try something and ask if you stuck with any errors so that some one can help you easily.

Comment: yes..Error: Required request body is missing.. @krishnathota

Comment: http method should be `POST` that's why you are seeing that error.

Comment: @krishnathota that's what my question is, Can we send for a GET Request? If its not possible, then how do we send by HashMap? I think how I am passing and accessing the hashmap is not the way it should be done in scenario 2...

Comment: Please don't ask the same question [again](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67775256/spring-boot-how-to-retrieve-request-object-send-though-exchange-http-get-method). Either update your previous question with relevant information or close it.

Comment: `GET` doesnt allow a request body to be sent

Answer (score 1):

HTTP post method needs to be used to send the body, get can have request parameters.

```
 ResponseEntity<UserResponse> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(
                url,
                HttpMethod.POST,
                requestEntity,
                UserResponse.class
        );
```

the request entity can be built like below.

```
//setting up the request headers
        HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
        requestHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);    

        //setting up the request body
        User user = new User();
        user.setName("Sample User");
        user.setUsername("user1");
        user.setPassword("pass123");

        //request entity is created with request body and headers
        HttpEntity<User> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(user, requestHeaders);
```

for more details go through [this](https://springbootdev.com/2017/11/21/spring-resttemplate-exchange-method/) link.